# Editors/IDEs for LaTeX documented source (.dtx) files

Tags: editors, ide

Similar to the question "[Latex Editors/IDEs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides)," I'm curious if there are any editors or add-ons that directly support the LaTeX documented source (.dtx) format.

I imagine such an editor would support syntax highlighting for both the implementation as well as the documentation, perhaps with different backgrounds to increase contrast between sections. Just as most editors will preserve indentation on newlines, it would also be helpful to preserve the leading `%` in documentation mode. Extra bonuses to support for `Doc`-specific macros.

Does such a thing exist? Do enough people actually edit `.dtx` files for there to be sufficient demand?

Comment: Thanks @Joseph. I'm still trying to figure out the vocabulary for all the different flavors of TeX. `:)`

Comment: No problem, that's what the experienced people are here for. The `.dtx` format is not limited to LaTeX, but as it's something the LaTeX Project came up with that's where the major use is.

Answer (score 13):

Several editors have a dedicated `.dtx` mode. Speaking from personal experience, the one for [WinEdt](http://www.winedt.com/) is very good if you want a 'heavy-weight' editor. As an alternative, [TeXworks](http://www.texworks.org/) is easy to customise with new syntax highlighting styles. I use a custom regex set with TeXworks for my `.dtx` editing:

```
[LaTeX DTX]

# comments
red        Y    \^\^A.*

# Guards
orange        N    %<(?:[A-Za-z0-9!\|]+|.)>
limegreen    N    %<\*(?:[A-Za-z0-9!\|]+|.)>
crimson        N    %</(?:[A-Za-z0-9!\|]+|.)>

# special characters
darkred        N    \^\^\^\^\^[0-9a-z]{5}
darkred        N    \^\^\^\^[0-9a-z]{4}
darkred        N    \^\^\^[0-9a-z]{3}
darkred        N    \^\^[0-9a-z]{2}
darkred        N    [$#^_{}&]
gray        N    ^%%.*
gray        N    ^%

# Macrocode
green        N    \\(?:begin|end)\{macrocode\}

# LaTeX environments
darkgreen    N    \\(?:begin|end)\s*\{[^}]*\}

# control sequences
blue        N    \\(?:[A-Za-z@:_]+|.)
```

Another common choice, but one I've not used, is [AUC-TeX](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/), which plugs into [Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/).

(I've covered [some detail about `.dtx` editing in my blog](http://www.texdev.net/2009/10/11/working-with-dtx-files/) in the past: the list of editors I give there is the same as the one I've given here.)

Comment: I just tested if WinEdit runs under Linux inside Wine. It does, and can call the Win32 binaries of TeXLive!

Answer (score 6):

You can do this with [Vim](http://www.vim.org/). It disables the '%' comments for `.dtx` files. You can reactivate it for all code inside the `{macrocode}` environments or even switch the language. This is shown by [Vim Tip 857](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/VimTip857).

I used this for `svn-multi-pl.dtx` which actually describes a Perl script.

Comment: I guessed as Emacs has something then Vim would ...

Comment: @Joseph: :-) ...

Answer (score 5):

As another option, I just threw together a solution for TextMate. It isn't terribly complicated, but some trickery is required to use the existing LaTeX language grammar for both the implementation and the documentation.

It has a few issues.  Most notably, many `.dtx` files do funny things with the catcode of `$`, and as such, TextMate will furiously try to match all `$`s, even when there isn't a matching pair.  Since some `.dtx` files can exceed 30k lines, this can lock up the parser for quite some time (in addition to parsing everything wrong after the `$`).

I [forked directly from the official `latex.tmbundle` on GitHub](https://github.com/mbauman/latex.tmbundle), but it could easily be integrated into the other branches.

Here's the language as a plain-text format plist:

```
{   scopeName = 'text.tex.latex.dtx';
    firstLineMatch = '^%\s*\\iffalse\s+(?:meta-)?comment';
    fileTypes = ( '.dtx' );
    patterns = (
        {   name = 'text.tex.latex.dtx.implementation';
            begin = '(?:^(%)    (\\begin){macrocode}|^(%)\s*(\\iffalse\b)(.*)$\n)';
            end = '(?:^(%)    (\\end){macrocode}|^(%)\s*(\\fi)\b)';
            beginCaptures = {
                1 = { name = 'comment.block.tex.latex.dtx'; };
                2 = { name = 'keyword.control.tex'; };
                3 = { name = 'comment.block.tex.latex.dtx'; };
                4 = { name = 'keyword.control.tex'; };
                5 = { name = 'comment.block.tex.latex.dtx'; };
            };
            endCaptures = {
                1 = { name = 'comment.block.tex.latex.dtx'; };
                2 = { name = 'keyword.control.tex'; };
                3 = { name = 'comment.block.tex.latex.dtx'; };
                4 = { name = 'keyword.control.tex'; };
            };
            patterns = (
                {   match = '^(%)(<[\*/]?(?:[A-Za-z0-9!\|]+|.)>)';
                    captures = {
                        1 = { name = 'comment.block.tex.latex.dtx'; };
                        2 = { name = 'entity.name.selection.tex.latex.dtx'; };
                    };
                },
                {   include = 'text.tex.latex'; },
            );
        },
        {   name = 'comment.block.tex.latex.dtx';
            match = '^%';
        },
        {   name = 'text.tex.latex.dtx.documentation';
            begin = '(\\CharacterTable)\b';
            end = '(?<!\\)}';
            beginCaptures = { 1 = { name = 'keyword.control.tex'; }; };
            patterns = (
                {   name = 'comment.block.tex.latex.dtx';
                    match = '^%';
                },
                {   name = 'markup.raw.charactertable';
                    match = '.';
                },
            );
        },
        {   include = 'text.tex.latex'; },
    );
}
```