# (How) Can I write a .dtx file without having to comment out *everything*?

Tags: dtx, literate-programming, docstrip

I have a reasonable understanding now of how `.dtx` files work. But it's a great pain having to put a `%` character before every line of documentation. Also, depending on which editor you're using, it basically means: *no syntax highlighting*.

This problem has been [noted](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31004/editor-for-dtx-files) before. But the only solutions offered were about editor settings. Plus, even if we forget about syntax highlighting, the `%` thing is just... inconvenient.

So I'm looking for a way to dispense with all the commenting. Basically, I'd like to delimit documentation code using guard modifiers. Something like this:

```
%<*documentation>
I'm going to introduce a cool new \LaTeX macro:
\begin{macrocode}
%</documentation>

\newcommand{\CoolNewMacro}{...}

%<*documentation>
\end{macrocode}
Cool, huh?
%</documentation>
```

I think I could figure out how to do it by first extracting the documentation code into a separate file. But... do I need to? Is there a better way?

Comment: If you want no comments, you can still use DocStrip, but not the standard `.dtx` format: is that an option? Of course, if you pick the right editor then highlighting and inserting the `%` is not an issue :-)

Comment: Well, I'll want to distribute my packages through CTAN, and I have the feeling that people are expecting the standard `.dtx` format. --- I just noted the 'editor solution' in my post. That's not really an option for me.

Comment: CTAN do not require `.dtx` files or really any particular structure. You might want to look for example at [`gmdoc`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/gmdoc).

Comment: Hm. I like the idea of `gmdoc`, but I'm finding it a bit hard to read the documentation (which is a shame, for a documentation package). You're sure it can do what I'm asking about in my question? And you're sure that `.dtx` *can't*?

Comment: @mhelvens You can also look at pgf and pgfplots documentation, I think they have done everything using a python script.

Comment: You can have a look at this if it is not very long http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47237/different-approach-to-literate-programming-for-latex, also the `tcolorbox` documentation.

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to use an editor which can not even do *that*.

Comment: @StephanLehmke I'd rather put it like this: I don't think it makes sense to use a language which requires you to prefix so many lines with a comment symbol. ;-)  ---  Anyway, I'm using Eclipse with the TeXLipse plugin. I pretty much use Eclipse for everything, and for LaTeX it has some great features (such as synctex). This just happens not to be one of them.

Comment: @mhelvens Aha. So how is this handeled in Java, for instance?

Comment: @StephanLehmke I guess you're talking about Javadoc. Two important differences: (1) it still allows you to delimit documentation with `/** */` thus not requiring you to comment every line. (2) There you write down only the bare minimum of information about defined classes and methods and documentation is automatically extracted. You don't write the manual.

Comment: @mhelvens "You don't write the manual." You don't need to do that in TeX either. The `.drv` usually mostly contains `\DocInput{\jobname.dtx}` and the whole doc is in the `.dtx`, but that's just convention. You can as well put the whole manual in the drv as a plain normal LaTeX document and input only the documented sources with `\DocInput{\jobname.dtx}`.

Comment: Or you simply write a separate manual as a separate LaTeX document altogether.

Comment: @StephanLehmke Good points. Let's just say that out of personal preference I'd still like to use only one file which uses delimiters, and leave it at that. :-) (I don't think we're supposed to be having discussions in the comments.)

Comment: By now the "doc - docstrip" workflow in the TeX community is a habit, and it seems that it won't change easily. I think you will fit right with coding in real literate-style instead of putting `%` at every line of documentation. Take a look at `noweb`. It's easy and useful.

Comment: Hi all! I just posted an answer to my own question. Feedback would be appreciated.  <###>  @JeanBaldraque: Thanks for the pointer! I'll check it out.

Comment: Maybe [makedtx](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/makedtx) is of help? "The makedtx bun­dle is pro­vided to help LaTeX2ε de­vel­op­ers to write the code and doc­u­men­ta­tion in sep­a­rate files, and then com­bine them into a sin­gle .dtx file for dis­tri­bu­tion. It au­to­mat­i­cally gen­er­ates the char­ac­ter ta­ble, and also writes the as­so­ci­ated in­stal­la­tion (.ins) script."

Comment: .note. Regarding "comfort" package gmdoc appears to have something interesting. There are other doc packages in `texdoc l3doc`. See also `codehigh`(light) package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so maybe it's not possible to do this elegantly using the 'standard' way of running the `.dtx` file through LaTeX to get the docs. But I have an alternative solution here which seems just as nice.

With this setup, there is only one file (the '`.ins` file' is included). You run it through LaTeX and it generates `package.sty` and `package.tex`. To get the actual documentation you still need to run `package.tex` itself through LaTeX. (A sacrifice I am willing to make.)

Here is a minimal working example (and a reasonable skeleton for anyone wanting to do the same):

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%  Copyright, license, etc... %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%% \CheckSum{3}
%%
%% \CharacterTable
%%  {Upper-case    \A\B\C\D\E\F\G\H\I\J\K\L\M\N\O\P\Q\R\S\T\U\V\W\X\Y\Z
%%   Lower-case    \a\b\c\d\e\f\g\h\i\j\k\l\m\n\o\p\q\r\s\t\u\v\w\x\y\z
%%   Digits        \0\1\2\3\4\5\6\7\8\9
%%   Exclamation   \!     Double quote  \"     Hash (number) \#
%%   Dollar        \$     Percent       \%     Ampersand     \&
%%   Acute accent  \'     Left paren    \(     Right paren   \)
%%   Asterisk      \*     Plus          \+     Comma         \,
%%   Minus         \-     Point         \.     Solidus       \/
%%   Colon         \:     Semicolon     \;     Less than     \<
%%   Equals        \=     Greater than  \>     Question mark \?
%%   Commercial at \@     Left bracket  \[     Backslash     \\
%%   Right bracket \]     Circumflex    \^     Underscore    \_
%%   Grave accent  \`     Left brace    \{     Vertical bar  \|
%%   Right brace   \}     Tilde         \~}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%<*driver>                                                                     %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\input docstrip.tex

\keepsilent

\usedir{tex/latex/package}

\nopreamble

\generate{
    \file{package.tex}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{d}}
    \file{package.sty}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{p}}
}

\obeyspaces
\Msg{*************************************************************}
\Msg{*                                                           *}
\Msg{* To finish the installation you have to move the following *}
\Msg{* file into a directory searched by TeX:                    *}
\Msg{*                                                           *}
\Msg{*     package.sty                                           *}
\Msg{*                                                           *}
\Msg{* To produce the documentation run the following file       *}
\Msg{* through LaTeX:                                            *}
\Msg{*                                                           *}
\Msg{*     package.tex                                           *}
\Msg{*                                                           *}
\Msg{* Happy TeXing!                                             *}
\Msg{*                                                           *}
\Msg{*************************************************************}

\endbatchfile

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%</driver>                                                                     %
%<*d>                                                                          %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\ProvidesFile{package.tex}

\documentclass{ltxdoc}

\usepackage{package}[2012/11/24]

\EnableCrossrefs         
\CodelineIndex
\RecordChanges

\changes{v0.0.1}{2012/11/16}{initial version}
\changes{v0.0.2}{2012/11/24}{put the package into a .dtx file}

\GetFileInfo{package.sty}

\DoNotIndex{\newcommand,\def,\xdef,\edef,\gdef,\NewDocumentCommand}

\title{The \textsf{package} package\thanks{This document
  corresponds to \textsf{package}~\fileversion, dated \filedate.}}
\author{Author Name \\ \texttt{author@mail.com}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}                                                               %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\maketitle

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{Introduction}                                                         %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

Put text here.

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{Usage}                                                                %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

Put text here.

\DescribeMacro{\dummyMacro}
This macro does nothing.

\DescribeEnv{dummyEnv}
This environment does nothing.

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{Implementation}\StopEventually{}                                      %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

The following piece of code contains the package meta-info:

\begin{verbatim}
%</d>%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    \NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2011/06/27]
    \ProvidesPackage{package}
        [2012/11/24 v0.0.2 description of the 'package' package]

%<*d>%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{verbatim}

\begin{macro}{\dummyMacro}
    This is a dummy macro.

    \begin{verbatim}
%</d>   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

        \newcommand{\dummyMacro}{}

%<*d>   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \end{verbatim}
\end{macro}

\begin{environment}{dummyEnv}
    This is a dummy environment.

    \begin{verbatim}
%</d>   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

        \newenvironment{dummyEnv}{}{}

%<*d>   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \end{verbatim}

    Some more information here... Very useful stuff.
\end{environment}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\Finale\end{document}                                                          %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Some remarks:

- The '`.ins`' part is terminated with `\endbatchfile`, so everything that comes afterwards is ignored on the first run. It is also delimited with `%<*driver>`, so it is itself ignored on subsequent runs.
- The copyright / licensing / file integrity stuff is automatically included in every generated file.
- In pure literate programming style, I made the package code 'submissive' to the documentation by my use of indentation. But you can choose to indent differently.

The only thing I couldn't get working was the `macrocode` environment. Perhaps it depends on the standard docstrip setup somehow? It was too hard to decipher its definition. So I'm using `verbatim` here to typeset the package code, but any code-typesetting technique (such as `listings`) would work.

Any feedback would be appreciated!

---

*Edit:* The previous version didn't work because I indented the guards. The `%<*bla>` code cannot have whitespace to its left. :-( Oh well. I also just noticed that the `verbatim` environment keeps all whitespace. (But there are solutions to that.)

Comment: One of the tasks that `doc` does is to properly index all of the code lines. If you do not use `macrocode` but `verbatim` that is not happening! Besides your solution has the same "defect" as mine, it will show the documentation guards. So I don't see what you gain, my solution does run directly off the .dtx and produces output comparable to yours, or not?. Speaking of decipering the doc code: you are reading the documented version or just the style file? I thought the former is fairly well documented.

Comment: @FrankMittelbach No, I'm getting clean code on my end. Have you actually run my code through LaTeX? ### Very good point about indexing the code. I'll take a look at the documented doc code.

Comment: I sure have. your file package.tex contains the guards and so they show up in the documentation. Just like they show up in my version in the documentation. The code is clean, yes, but so is mine if you run a .ins file to extract the code. Did you try it?

Comment: @FrankMittelbach You're right! I don't know how that happened. I had a version yesterday which definitely didn't show the guards, and I thought I copied it exactly. I'm going to figure this out. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: @FrankMittelbach It was because I indented the guards. Apparently you can't (too bad).

Comment: Do I understand this correctly that you included a reference to a `p`-guard in your `.ins` code (perhaps, for generality), but you actually didn't need any `p`-guards in your example code?

Comment: @imz--IvanZakharyaschev: To be honest, I don't remember. This is all pretty long ago for me. ;-)

Comment: Did you ever find a solution, where the `<*d>` tags are not needed? Accidential output of unguarded parts to *all* output files is the most common source of error for me.

Answer (score 12):

If you look at the history of `doc`, then it is understandable why the current system works as it works. Initially the idea as to write a `.sty` file with the comments imbedded, but in a way that it would directly be processable by LaTeX. And that required putting every bit of documentation behind `%` signs.

Only later docstrip appeared (to strip the comments because back then processing all those unnecessary comment lines took noticable extra time). Even later the `<guards>` appeared and with them none-sequencial generation of target files. At that time the name of the files changed to `.dtx` and one could then have changed the documentation part to work without `%` --- but that didn't happen.

Having said this, one can with a little modification run doc in that form, e.g.,

```
%<*documentation>
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{doc}

\makeatletter
\def\inlinecode{\macro@code
   \frenchspacing \@vobeyspaces
   \xinline@code}
\let\endinlinecode\endmacrocode

\begingroup
\catcode`\|=\z@ \catcode`\[=\@ne \catcode`\]=\tw@
\catcode`\{=12 \catcode`\}=12
\catcode`\\=\active
|gdef|xinline@code#1\end{inlinecode}[#1|end[inlinecode]]
|endgroup
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\noindent some text
\begin{inlinecode}
%</documentation>
\def\foo{bar}
%<*documentation>
\end{inlinecode}
more text
\end{document}
%</documentation>
```

To the processable code out of this file one would need a `docstrip` install file like

```
\input docstrip

\generate{\file{x.sty}{\from{how-can-i-write-a-dtx-file-without-having-to-comment-out-everything.dtx}{}}}

\endbatchfile
```

But it isn't fully satisfying, as the documentation guards show up in the documentation and without some serious changes to `docstrip` and `doc` I don't see a way to get rid of those:

[image]

perhaps it would look a little better in print if we call the guard "code" (but then * and / are in the wrong order)  --- either way it is suboptimal.

### Update

If one wants to get rid of the documentation guards, one simple solution is of course to use docstrip to generate a separate documentation file as it was suggested already by the OP. To do this all one has to do is to additionally provide the line

```
\generate{\file{packagedoc.tex}{\from{how-can-i-write-a-dtx-file-without-having-to-comment-out-everything.dtx}{documentation}}}
```

in the `.ins` file and then run LaTeX on the resulting file. However, to fully utialize the features of `doc`, e.g., the code indexing or the code line numbering it is imortant to use the `macrocode` environment. As this environment uses the special syntax with `%    \end{macrocode}` it can't be used directly at least not if one wants to avoid putting the `%` in. Therefore the code above defining the `inlinecode` environment as an alternative is essential.

Perhaps that bit of code should be added to doc to allow for this approach.

Comment: Hi! Your catcode-intensive solution is very interesting, but I find it a bit hard to follow (as I do all catcode-intensive TeX code).  -<###>-  And I have to say, the fact that those tags would remain visible in the documentation makes this solution... unacceptable. :-) I think the answer I just proposed myself is a bit more workable.  -<###>-  Nonetheless, I'll have some fun puzzling out your catcodes later. Cheers!

Comment: @mhelvens with a bit more effort it is possible to suppress the documentation guards and leave just an empty line there. Getting rid of that line is more difficult as with \CodelineIndex the line would have a number attached. The catcode tricks are the same as used in doc.dtx, so reading its documentation should help :-). As to the visible guards: your solution shows them too, so why  do you think it is more workable?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the skeleton of the dtx of a package I have written and which will appear in a few days on CTAN (the current version on CTAN does not yet have this structure of the dtx file)

```
%<*none>
% This skeleton PKG.dtx file is one way to not have everything commented
% out in the documentation part. It produces the .sty file (and also an
% .ins file) when one does latex PKG.dtx.
%
% It *does not* use DocInput!
% 
% It is also possible to not produce the .sty file, and still be able to
% compile the doc, using some boolean flag, and doing an \input which
% will get only the code, the only thing is that the log file will
% complain that we have required package `' and that package `PKG' was
% used.
%
% Here we rather first output the .sty file, and then do a normal
% \usepackage 
%
% [I am of course assuming that compiling the doc for package PKG 
%  does require the use of PKG.sty]
%
\begingroup
\input docstrip.tex
\askforoverwritefalse
\generate{
\file{PKG.ins}{\from{PKG.dtx}{ins}}
\file{PKG.sty}{\from{PKG.dtx}{package}}
\nopreamble\nopostamble
\file{test.txt}{\from{PKG.dtx}{test}}}
\endgroup
\iffalse
%</none>
%<*ins>
\input docstrip.tex
\askforoverwritefalse
\generate{\file{PKG.sty}{\from{PKG.dtx}{package}}}
\endbatchfile
%</ins>
%<*test>
This is a another file which can be produced by the latex run
%</test>
%<*none>
\fi
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
% \OnlyDescription
\usepackage{PKG} % <- often needed to produce its own documentation!
\begin{document}
I am the best packaging package.

\makeatletter
\StopEventually{\check@checksum\end{document}}
\makeatother

\MakePercentIgnore

% \catcode`\<=0 \catcode`\>=11 \catcode`\*=11 \catcode`\/=11 
%
% \let</none>\relax
% \def<*package>{\catcode`\<=12 \catcode`\>=12 \catcode`\*=12 \catcode`\/=12}
%
%</none>
%<*package>
%    \begin{macrocode}
\ProvidesPackage{PKG}
 [2012/11/24 v1.04 easy packaging (jfB)]
%    \end{macrocode}
% Let us point out the importance of this piece of code with 31
% \cs{expandafter}'s
%    \begin{macrocode}
\endinput
%    \end{macrocode}
% \MakePercentComment
%</package>
\CharacterTable
 {Upper-case    \A\B\C\D\E\F\G\H\I\J\K\L\M\N\O\P\Q\R\S\T\U\V\W\X\Y\Z
  Lower-case    \a\b\c\d\e\f\g\h\i\j\k\l\m\n\o\p\q\r\s\t\u\v\w\x\y\z
  Digits        \0\1\2\3\4\5\6\7\8\9
  Exclamation   \!     Double quote  \"     Hash (number) \#
  Dollar        \$     Percent       \%     Ampersand     \&
  Acute accent  \'     Left paren    \(     Right paren   \)
  Asterisk      \*     Plus          \+     Comma         \,
  Minus         \-     Point         \.     Solidus       \/
  Colon         \:     Semicolon     \;     Less than     \<
  Equals        \=     Greater than  \>     Question mark \?
  Commercial at \@     Left bracket  \[     Backslash     \\
  Right bracket \]     Circumflex    \^     Underscore    \_
  Grave accent  \`     Left brace    \{     Vertical bar  \|
  Right brace   \}     Tilde         \~}

\CheckSum{2}

\Finale
%%
%% End of file
```

The actual situation in my dtx file is more complicated, I simplified things here to get that skeleton. I agree that having all those % is indeed a problem, although with emacs there is a mode which does the LaTeX syntax highlighting nevertheless. So I was also interested in finding a way not to have all those `%`'s.

Oups, I forgot to say that the `ins` stuff is purely optional. It is only to produce an `.ins` file, but it is not used, as the `.sty` file itself is directly output.

Comment: Ah, I see. The trick here, then, is to manually call `\MakePercentIgnore` before starting the 'implementation' section. So you have most of the documentation without the `%`s, but you still need them for that last section. Correct? Interesting solution.

Comment: @mhelvens: Yes, the commenting of the source code is still done with the `%`, in the standard manner. But the user manual can be entirely written without the `%`. The important thing is when I realized I should forget entirely about using `\DocInput`!!

Comment: Yes, I did the same thing in my own solution, but took it a bit further. I'm not commenting out lines of code *anywhere*. Whether or not that's better can be debated. But I suppose you could say that my solution is more purely *literate programming*, as the program is 'submissive' to the documentation. That is to say: it is merely part of the story. In your solution, the documentation still takes a back seat, so to say. But I suppose this is bordering on the philosophical.

Comment: @mhelvens: interesting! I didn't think about going as far as you did, simply because Emacs handles beautifully the `%` at the start of lines, it is just as if they were not there for syntax highlighting and automatized filling. However in the `user manual` part I may have to copy paste to plain `.tex` file and then the `%` are slightly a nuisance. So I was mainly keen on getting rid of them in this `user manual` part, before the commented source code.

Comment: @mhelvens: and of course no line of code is commented out in the implementation part, only the lines of commenting are commented out, in the standard `macrocode` manner.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I'm actually thinking of switching to a somewhat similar approach, since mine seems to have some problems w.r.t. indentation. <>---<> If I just manually write the `.sty` file with doc/macrocode comments inside, it doesn't have to be generated at all. It's already there! The documentation can be a simple `.tex` file which uses `\DocInput` to typeset the implementation.